# Using 3-way to select between two loads

Tags: electrical

Is it ok to use a 3-way switch to select between two different loads? I don't see it being used this way -- is there some sort of safety or code violation? If so, what are some alternatives?

Here's the background:
I have a bathroom fan with both exhaust and heater. Each has its own fan (and switch), so it wouldn't make much sense to have both the heater and exhaust on. It would just suck all the warm air from heater out.  Currently, they're wired to a single-pole triple switch, next to a regular light switch.

I'm thinking to use a 3-way switch as a "selector" to determine between exhaust / heater.  And then upgrade the adjacent light switch with a dual-load occupancy/humidity detect. So the exhaust/heater will only run when needed, and will shut-off automatically.

[image]

Comment: I've had very bad experience with humidity sensors. In Canada, where we have both 30C and -30C, there doesn't seem to be a sensitivity setting that will work all year round. Short of having your exhaust working all the time, half the year, expect to need to re-adjust it twice a year. Or maybe it would work in Texas :-)

Comment: @Jeffrey does it differ summer to winter?  Air has very different humidity content at different temperatures.  Outside air at 30C will tend to be 100% relative humidity at room temperature.  Outside air at -30C will be 0% relative humidity when heated to room temp.  So if your definition of "works" is "runs everytime I shower", that may not be possible.

Comment: yeah: winter "during shower" humidity requiring venting is actually lower that normal summer humidity. So, either: it vents during the whole summer or it never vents during winter or I re-adjust them every spring/fall. We eventually rip them out and trained the family to manual use the fan.

Comment: @Jeffrey Thanks for the heads-up on the humidity sensor. For the purpose of this question, can replace humidity sensor with a timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that. It's the way they are usually wired and they usually come with their own 3-way switch. Are you sure what's there is a single-pole triple switch?  Sometimes they throw in a 3-way in the combo.